# Create object of template inner class

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

I have template class with inner class

```
template<class param>
class Nested {
    param obj;
public:
    template<class X>
    class Inner {
        X obj;
    public:
        Inner(X obj) : obj(obj) {}
        X getObj() { return obj; }
    };
    Nested();
    Nested(param obj) : obj(obj) {}
    param getObj() { return obj; }
    virtual ~Nested();
};
```

I try:

```
Nested<int>::Inner<int> inner(43);
```

but i get compilation error:

```
C++/TemplateClass/Debug/../src/TemplateClass.cpp:20: undefined reference to `Nested<int>::~Nested()'
C++/TemplateClass/Debug/../src/TemplateClass.cpp:20: undefined reference to `Nested<int>::~Nested()'
```

and next posiblities:

```
    Nested<int>::Inner inner(43);

../src/TemplateClass.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/TemplateClass.cpp:17:24: error: invalid use of template-name ‘Nested<int>::Inner’ without an argument list
  typename Nested<int>::Inner inner(43);
                        ^
../src/TemplateClass.cpp:17:35: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘(’ token
  typename Nested<int>::Inner inner(43);
                                   ^
../src/TemplateClass.cpp:18:42: error: request for member ‘getObj’ in ‘inner’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
  cout << "Inner param object: " << inner.getObj() << endl;
```

How can I create Inner class object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a type for the inner class

```
Nested<int>::Inner<char> inner(43);
```

and add some code to your destructor

```
virtual ~Nested() {}
```

Comment: When i do like that i get compilation error undefined reference to `Nested<int>::~Nested()'

Comment: @user3574580: try to add some code to your destructor: virtual ~Nested() {}.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

It works as intended. For this narrow example you don't need to define a destructor for Nested<> because a Nested<> instance is not created.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class param>
class Nested {
    param obj;
public:
    template<class X>
    class Inner {
        X obj;
    public:
        Inner(X obj) : obj(obj) {}
        X getObj() { return obj; }
    };
    Nested();
    Nested(param obj) : obj(obj) {}
    param getObj() { return obj; }
    virtual ~Nested();
};

int main()
{
    Nested<int>::Inner<int> temp(43);
    std::cout << temp.getObj() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```